# How to create and compare datetimes in custom class?

Tags: python, class, datetime

I'm writing `__init__` and `__eq__` functions for the class `Photo`, involving the `datetime` module. However, I'm unsure of the `__init__` function body I've written and how to test `__eq__`.

This is what I have for the `__init__` function:

```
class Photo:
    'Fields: size, pdate'
    # Purpose: constructor for class Photo
    # __init__: Int Int Int Int -> Photo
    # Note: Function definition needs a self parameter and does not require a return statement
    def __init__(self, size, year, month, day):
        self.size = size
        self.pdate = year + month + day
```

I think that my `self.pdate` is wrong but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to write instead. Perhaps the following?

```
self.pdate = year
self.date = month
self.date = day
```

Comment: what exactly are you comparing? If you are using dates then just compare datetimes

Comment: You're talking about the datetime module but not using it. Maybe you should take a look at [creating such objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#date-objects)

Comment: This is my first time working with the datetime module and I'm having trouble understanding it

Comment: What part of "class datetime.date(year, month, day)" do you not understand?

Comment: I don't know which of "year","month","day" to assign to self.pdate

Comment: Is your question "How to create and compare datetimes in custom class?" then? If yes, can you edit your title?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes thats actually a good way to explain my question

Comment: If you don't know how to use the `datetime` module, you should start by reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#date-objects), you can create `datetime.date` objects using the following:

```
from datetime import date

some_random_date = date(2013, 7, 28)
not_so_random = date.today()
```

For your use case, this is the kind of objects you want to affect to your `self.pdate` attribute:

```
from datetime import date

class Photo:
    'Fields: size, pdate'
    # Purpose: constructor for class Photo
    # __init__: Int Int Int Int -> Photo
    # Note: Function definition needs a self parameter and does not require a return statement
    def __init__(self, size, year, month, day):
        self.size = size
        self.pdate = date(year, month, day)
```

and in order to compare two of your objects:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Test that other is also a Photo, left as an exercise
        return self.size == other.size and self.pdate == other.pdate
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.size != other.size or self.pdate != other.pdate
```

Comment: the __ ne __ function checks if they're not equal?

Comment: @ShagunChhikara Yep, rationale [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/)